# How to declare int array in Vue.JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to declare an integer Array but don't know how to do this. Is it possible to declare a int array in Vue.

Comment: It’s JavaScript. Arrays are not Vue specific.

Answer (score 2):

In your script , just add this below :

```
data(){
    return {
        your_array : [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
}
```

your_array is just an example, the variable name can be any anything.